# How to save var value outside ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make some form validation functions. Here is what I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var myObj = {}; 

$('#username').keyup(function () {

    id = $(this).attr('id');
    validateUsername(id);       

});

function validateUsername(id){

var username = $("#"+id).val();

    $.ajax({
        url : "validate.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action=usr_id&id=' + username,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {

            if (data.ok == true) {

                $(myObj).data("username","ok");

            } else {


                $(myObj).data("username","no");

            }

        }
    }); 


} // end validateusername function


$('#submit').click(function(){

    if (myObj.username == "ok")  {

        alert("Username OK");

    } else {

        alert("Username BAD");

    }   


});




}); // end doc ready
```

So you can see, when a key is pressed in the textbox, it checks if it's valid. The "data.ok" comes back correctly. The problem is based on the response, I define $(myObj).username. For some reason, I can't get this value to work outside the validateusername function. When clicking the submit button, it has no idea what the value of $(myObj).username is.

I need to use something like this, because with multiple form fields on the page to validate, I can do something like:

```
if (myObj.username && myObj.password && myObj.email == "ok")
```

... to check all my form fields before submitting the form.

I know I must just be missing something basic.... any thoughts?

EDIT: SOLVED

All I had to do was change **var myObj = {};** to **myObj = {};** and it's working like a charm. I think I've been staring at this screen waaaaay too long!

Comment: Good luck getting ajax to keep up with someone's typing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not accessing the data that you stored properly. Access the username value this way:

```
$(myObj).data("username")
```

**Resources:**

Take a look at jQuery's [.data() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

[Very simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/aZXy2/) that shows how to properly set and retrieve data with jQuery's .data() method.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was looking at the wrong one. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the promise in that global variable and then bind an event to the done event within your submit button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var myObj = false; 

$('#username').keyup(function () {

    id = $(this).attr('id');
    validateUsername(id);       

});

function validateUsername(id){

    var username = $("#"+id).val();

    myObj = $.ajax({
        url : "validate.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action=usr_id&id=' + username,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#username').removeClass('valid invalid');
          if (data.ok == true) {
            $('#username').addClass('valid');
          }
          else {
            $('#username').addClass('invalid');
          }
        }
    }); 


} // end validateusername function


$('#submit').click(function(){

    // if myObj is still equal to false, the username has
    // not changed yet, therefore the ajax request hasn't
    // been made
    if (!myObj) {
        alert("Username BAD");
    }
    // since a deferred object exists, add a callback to done
    else {
        myObj.done(function(data){
            if (data.ok == true) {
                alert("Username BAD");
            }
            else {
                alert("Username OK");
            }               
        });
    }

});




}); // end doc ready
```

you may want to add some throttling to the keyup event though to prevent multiple ajax requests from being active at once.

Comment: After changing the first line to "myObj = false" (removed the var), this worked, but the problem with this is that myObj will vary depending on the result returned from the POST. That's what I had it in the success function...

Comment: you can think of the "done" function i'm using as the success function that you were previously using. Can't you just put that additional logic there? I'm not sure why removing var from the first line would make any difference there, it all should be scoped correctly.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Add the success method back with only that functionality, dont actually modify myObj within the success event. i'll update example.

Comment: I just got my original code working... your post gave me the idea- all I did was remove "var" from myObj = {}; and now it's working like a charm!